# High Sierra asking me for disk password

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, password, high-sierra

I have been having a nightmare since I decided to update to `High Sierra`. 
High Sierra was failing to install on my HD disk prompting me with the error discussed here (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87690)

I managed to install the OS on a pen drive and boot from there, then, after creating a backup of my files I converted my HD disk to APFS using disk utility and restarted my computer with  `cmd` + `R`

When starting the installation High Sierra installer asks me for my drive password in order to mount it and begin the installation. I set the password and it proceeds.

The problem comes after it finishes downloading and it reboots. I am presented with a screen asking me for my disk password. I enter the same password I use in order to mount my disk but it keeps rejecting it.
I am SURE I am typing the password correctly, with no caps, or spaces.

My concern is if the password being asked is the same password I use to unencrypt my disk and mount it. I am not sure how to proceed now. Pretty frustrating week trying to install High Sierra.

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated.

EDIT: I found this link (https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80174) with a solution to some people. In my case, it fails because there I have no `/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default` directory... All I see on my original drive is `/var/db/PreviousSystemFiles.plist` and `/var/db/PreviousSystemLogs.cpgz`

EDIT 2: Warning, if you go for the option above, make sure to backup your `/users/` folder. In some tests I made I found out that after doing the above, High Sierra ends up overwriting the whole folder thus losing all data.

Comment: Do you use a QWERTY keyboard?
If not, try typing QWERTY equivalent characters...

Comment: Hi, yes, I tried that. I even tried the small keyboard icon on the top right corner and selecting different languages. No luck. I am seeing more people facing the same issue https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/72eice/high_sierra_password_no_longer_works_no_option/ This is a mess...

Comment: If you’ve converted a hard drive to APFS, then you’re probably screwed. High Sierra at present only supports APFS for SSDs.

Comment: Thanks, @MikeScott, I don't see that in the requirements https://support.apple.com/kb/SP765?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US ... anyway, I just found out, it completely wiped my /users folder, deleting all my information. Since I downloaded it everything has been a nightmare.